# Crear un WebService en ASP.NET que regrese indefinido numero de columnas de una base de datos

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, asp

Normalmente esta es la estructura de un WebService que uso en un proyecto, pero ahora necesito traer todas las columnas de una tabla que puede tener N numero de columnas, en el ejemplo solo recibo 4 columnas que se que existen, pero que pasa cuando tengo 12, 15 o 20 columnas cuyos nombres no se conocen y quiero que reciban el mismo trato por medio del WebService (convertir a json).

La tabla que regresa N numero de columnas es generada con un query dinamico en SQL y cambia el numero de columnas constantemente.

```
[WebMethod]
        public string getInformacion()
        {
            List<condDet> p = new List<condDet>();

            string ConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTS"].ToString();

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectString))
            {
                string qry = "SELECT * FROM TABLAEJEMPLO";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = qry;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = cn;

                cn.Open();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        condDet cpData = new condDet();
                        cpData.NOMBRE = dr["NOMBRE"].ToString();
                        cpData.EXC = dr["EXC"].ToString();
                        cpData.PAIS = dr["PAIS"].ToString();
                        cpData.NOMBRE_PAIS = dr["NOMBRE_PAIS"].ToString();
                        p.Add(cpData);
                    }
                }
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
                return json;
            }
        }

public class condDet
    {
        public string NOMBRE { get; set; }
        public string EXC { get; set; }
        public string PAIS { get; set; }
        public string NOMBRE_PAIS { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Tu problema es teorico? porque lo que vas a devolver es un array de array en ese caso... y despues que se encargue el front de hacer magia

Comment: Ese es solo un ejemplo para mostrar que para cada columna que me regresa hago uso de set y get e itero con el nombre de las columnas. En mi problema real no se cuantas columas serán y necesito saber como manejerlas pues no puedo estar editando el web service cada que se agregue una nueva columna a la tabla que haré referencia

Comment: Es lo que te dije antes entonces. Tendras un array que contendra otro array variable. Ahora, si tu tabla va a cambiar a cada rato, algo muy raro le pasa.

Comment: Podrias usar un ejemplo sencillo con codigo? para entender mejor, la tabla se genera automaticamente por queries dinamicos en forma de vista, es su comportamiento normal segun el proceso

Comment: no se que queres que te ejemplifique. La clase? tiene una sola propiedad. una List<List<String>>().

Comment: No lo hagas con **SqlDataReader** mejor emplea **SqlDataAdapter** y has un **Fill** a un datatable, así dará igual cuantas columnas tengas, después de eso sólo bastaría serializar el dataTable para convertirlo a json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un DataTable que se cargue directo de la consulta

```
DataTable dtTabla = new DataTable();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dtTabla.Load(dr);
dr.Close();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtTabla);
return json;
```